# Buscar data 7 dias antes da data actual php

Tags: php

Em PHP queria ir buscar o primeiro dia e o ultimo dia dos últimos 7 dias. Tenho a data actual:

```
$data_actula = date("Y-m-d");
```

Agora quero ir buscar os data 7 dias atrás. Por exemplo, hoje é dia 2014-07-29, quero achar o valor 2014-07-22. Com isto tenho que ter sempre em atenção as mudanças dos meses. Como posso chegar a este valor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A classe [DateTime](http://www.php.net/class.datetime) é muito mais preferível para manipular data/hora e relativos:

```
<?php

date_default_timezone_set( 'America/Sao_Paulo' );


$time = new DateTime( '2014-07-29' );

print '<pre>'; print_r( $time ); print '</pre>';

$time -> sub( new DateInterval( 'P7D' ) );

print '<pre>'; var_dump( $time, $time -> format( 'Y-m-d' ) ); print '</pre>';
```

O único pequeno inconveniente é a exigência do objeto [DateInterval](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) para se subtrair (ou adicionar) um intervalo de tempo pois ele tem uma sintaxe [um pouquinho diferenciada](http://php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.construct.php), baseada na especificação [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iso8601#Durations)

Comment: 1+ Por usar `DateTime`.

Answer (score 5):

```
<?php
   //Precisa de definir a função abaixo para evitar warnings
   date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
   //Sua data original
   $Date = "2014-07-29";
   //Modifica a data (7 dias atrás) 
   $data_actula = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($Date. ' - 7 days'));
   //Mostra resultado
   echo $data_actula;
?>
```

Note que se quiser adicionar é bem parecido:

```
$data_actula = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($Date. ' + 7 days'));
```

Comment: É isso mesmo. Muito obrigado!

Comment: Apesar de adequado ao exemplo, sem querer ser chato,  aconselho o uso dos objetos DateTime e DateInterval se existir cálculos de comparação.

Comment: @neoprofit, concordo com o que disse e at'e acho interessante o fato de ter uma resposta que cobre o `DateTime` mas, achei que devido a pergunta ter sido feita usando `date()` que o OP gostaria da resposta mantendo o tipo.

Comment: @Kyllopardiun vc está certo!

Comment: Eu acho que n'ao demora e a pr[opria DateTime vai passar a considerar o tipo de argumento que strtotime() aceita.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode resolver isso da seguinte maneira também:

```
<?php
$data_actula    = date("Y-m-d");
$danta_anterior = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($data_actula) - (7 * 24 * 60 * 60));
```

Veja executando aqui: http://3v4l.org/0CVHY

Answer (score 1):

Ainda assim, é possível usar o `DateInterval` de um jeito mais fácil, se você não estiver acostumando com os parâmetros da instanciação dela, como eu. Basta apenas usar o método `DateTime::createFromDateString()`;

Veja:

```
$time = new DateTime('2014-07-29', new DateTimeZone('America/Sao_Paulo'));

print_r($time);

$time->sub(DateInterval::createFromDateString('-7 days'));

var_dump($time,$time->format( 'Y-m-d' ));
```