# Como atribuir mais 60 dias numa data em relação a data de hoje em PHP?

Tags: php

Estou atribuindo a data de hoje em uma variável, gostaria de saber como faço para atribuir a data de hoje mais 60 dias. Como seria a sintaxe ?

```
$dateIni = date('Y-m-d');
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Você pode passar um segundo argumento para `date` para especificar a data, através de um timestamp. Nesse caso, vamos usar `strtotime` para facilitar o serviço (essa função cria um timestamp baseado numa string que represente a quantidade de tempo desejada).

```
$dateIni = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+60 days'));
```

Também é possível fazer através da classe `DateTime` - a qual eu sempre prefiro usar.

Veja:

```
$date = new DateTime('+60 days');

echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

Se estiver usando o PHP 5.4 >=, ainda pode fazer assim:

```
 echo (new DateTime('+60 days')->format('Y-m-d');
```

Para fixar o conhecimento sobre datas em PHP, vou linkar algumas perguntas importantes sobre o assunto:

- [Descobrir a próxima data a partir do dia da semana](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/50662/descobrir-a-pr%C3%B3xima-data-a-partir-do-dia-da-semana/50716#50716)
- [Buscar data 7 dias antes da data actual php](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/26976/buscar-data-7-dias-antes-da-data-actual-php?rq=1)
- [Como saber se a data de hoje é sábado ou domingo (final de semana) em PHP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/136778/como-saber-se-a-data-de-hoje-%C3%A9-s%C3%A1bado-ou-domingo-final-de-semana-em-php)